# How do I get an image from an Image Library app using the SharePoint JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to write a SharePoint web part for an on-line SharePoint-hosted site. I have looked around but can't find more than how to access a basic list. I need to access a list created by the Image Libary app, but when I look at the list columns in my admin UI, I can only see text columns, and I have only figured out how to access these text columns in my js code:"

```
var oneList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle("RotatingBannerImages");
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
this.listItems = oneList.getItems(query);
context.load(listItems);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler() {
    var itemEnum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (itemEnum.moveNext()) {
        var item = itemEnum.get_current();
        console.log(item.get_item("Title")); // Returns null on image list.
    }
}
```

The expression `item.get_item("Title")` returns a list item title when I access a plain text list, which I used to establish my API code before moving on the Image Library list. Nearly everything I try in the debugger returns an object, which needs another round of method calls just to inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 options how to access List Item properties via SharePoint JSOM.

The following example demonstrates how to access [SP.ListItem.id property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246416(v=office.15).aspx):

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Images");
var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
ctx.load(items);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {

       for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++) {
           var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);    

           console.log(item.get_item("ID")); // 1st Option 
           console.log(item.get_fieldValues().ID); // 2nd Option
           console.log(item.get_id()); // 3d Option
       }
    },
    function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

**Option 1**

Using [SP.ListItem.item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245189(v=office.15).aspx) to get or sets the specified field value, for example to return  image url of list item in Images library:

```
var imageUrl = item.get_item("FileRef")
```

**Option 2**

[SP.ListItem.fieldValues property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244802(v=office.15).aspx) stores a collection of key/value pairs containing the names and values for the fields of the list item, for example:

```
var imageUrl = item.get_fieldValues().FileRef;
```

or

```
var imageUrl = item.get_fieldValues()['FileRef'];
```

**Option 3**

[SP.ListItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245356(v=office.15).aspx) exposes some properties like [SP.ListItem.id property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246416(v=office.15).aspx), for example:

```
var itemId = item.get_id();
```

Comment: Thanks for a very informative answer, @Vadim, but my real problem is not to access item properties, but that I don't know which properties to access to get my image data and or url.

Answer (score 0):

You must load File details, here the code

```
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Pictures");

var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
this.listItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(listItems);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler() {
    var itemEnum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (itemEnum.moveNext()) {
        var item = itemEnum.get_current();
        this.fileImg = item.get_file();
        context.load(fileImg);

        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, successFile),
            Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
        );
    }
}

function successFile() {
    console.log(fileImg.get_name());
    console.log(fileImg.get_serverRelativeUrl());
}

function errorHandler()
{
    console.log("Error");
}
```

Anyway if you can use jquery I suggest you to use REST as follow; as you can see you write less code;

```
var urlAll = "http://mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('RotatingBannerImages')/items?$expand=File"

$.ajax({
    url : urlAll,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var files  = data.d.results;
        files.forEach(function(item){
            console.log(item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
            console.log(item.File.Name);
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not correct, if you dont need file specific properties, you dont have to load associated file object at all. For example such properties like file name and url could be easily retrieved from FileLeafRef and FileRef List Item properties